# Fixed background not working in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, background, background-attachment

I have `background-attachment: fixed;` on my hero section and it works in firefox and safari but not in chrome. I can get it to work by changing to `position:relative;` and `z-index: -1;` but then the buttons within the hero become unusable and this also creates problems in firefox and safari.

```
#hero {
padding-top: 60px;
background-attachment: fixed;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center;
background-size: cover;
}
```

I tried changing the parent positions to static based on other post I found but that didn't work either.

http://bayarddev.com/fca/about-us/

Comment: works for me: http://imgur.com/X9lkJwC. Maybe try clearing your cache. You can always try an incognito window if you don't know how to clear your cache (ctrl+shift+n).

Comment: can you post your html?

Comment: Not working in Chrome for me either, are you using anything that would promote it to a new layer such as transform Z or backface-visibility?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I see it now. On `.hero`'s parent element `.off-canvas-wrap` and `.inner-wrap` you are using `-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden`. If you turn this off the background attachment works fine.